# How to prevent codeigniter to use cache

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I am logging out form  my account than page is redirecting me to login page . But if i am pressing back button then it is showing me all the previous pages i visit.

I dont know where to set or reset it.

**Please check my logout function**

```
/**
 * Logout user
 */
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    logout_user();
    redirect('login');
}
```

I even set a function to get user details in

```
 parent::__construct();
    // redirect to Login page if user not logged in
    $this->mUser = get_user();
    if ( empty($this->mUser) )
    {
        redirect('login');
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- **You cant control Browser back button**. For that you can **check** each and every **controller/method** whether `session` is set or not.
- if set allow user to view page
- if not redirect the page to login

  ```
  public function login()
  {
          $session = array(
          'username'  => $name,
          'logged_in' => TRUE
      );

      $this->session->set_userdata($session);
  }


  public function home()
  {
      $user = $this->session->userdata('username');//check session is set
      if(empty($user))
      {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Session has Expired');
          redirect('controller/method');//loging page
      }
      else
      {
          $this->load->view("my_view");
      }
  }
  ```

> **NOTE :** I have already running with this Error. I found lot of possible answers but this one only effects.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is browser cache issue, So try to add the following to the pages where users are required to be logged in:

```
//Prevent browsers from using history to browse in the user system.
$this->CI->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->CI->output->set_header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
$this->CI->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Please take a look below threads, hope you will get some more help from there:

[Browser Cache issue in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429386/browser-cache-issue-in-codeigniter?rq=1)

[logout issue in code igniter (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092479/logout-issue-in-code-igniter-php?rq=1)